# How to convert a string to an javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a string which looks like luis,philip .It having comma in between them but i have to make an array with it.I am trying with json.Parse but it is not working i am posting  my code

```
var names = 'luis,philip' ;
var nameArray = JSON.parse("[" + names +"]");
```

but it showing error in json parsing ,please somebody help

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var names = 'luis,philip';
var namesArray = name.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string and get the array.

```
var names = 'luis,philip';
var arr = names.split(','); // ['luis', 'philip']
```